# Call without gas fees

Tags: substrate-node-template, nft, polkadot-sdk

In a custom pallet I wrote an entry point that's supposed to be called by root. The purpose of the function is to create a collection with specific metadata at the NFTs pallet. I am using dummy data in this post, in reality the metadata is much more than this.

The idea is that no gas fee will be charged, however I am not accomplishing that with this code. Tests fail, because the pallet's account (which is used as the owner of the collection) has no funds.

Is there a way to ensure this function can be called without gas fees? If there is a better way to reach my goal then I'm also open to that. What matters is that the collections used by this pallet get created with specific metadata.

```rust
        #[pallet::call_index(0)]
        #[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::do_something())]
        pub fn create_collections(origin: OriginFor<T>, admin: Option<T::AccountId>) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
            // Check that the extrinsic was signed by root.
            ensure_root(origin)?;           

            let account_id = Self::account_id();
            let admin = admin.unwrap_or(account_id.clone());

            //== Experience credentials ==//
            // Create collection
            T::Nfts::create_collection_with_id(
                T::ExperienceNFTCollectionId::get(), 
                &account_id, 
                &admin,
                &CollectionConfig {
                    settings: CollectionSettings::from_disabled(
                        CollectionSetting::TransferableItems | CollectionSetting::UnlockedMetadata
                    ),
                    max_supply: None,
                    mint_settings: MintSettings::default(),
                })?;

            // Set collection metadata.
            T::Nfts::set_collection_metadata(None, &T::ExperienceNFTCollectionId::get(), &[0,1])?;
            
            Ok(Pays::No.into())
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this post [how we can implement gasless/feeless transaction?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1713/how-we-can-implement-gasless-feeless-transaction/1715#1715) and you can also try the following code it might help you.

```rust
        #[pallet::call_index(0)]
        #[pallet::weight(Pays::No)]
        pub fn create_collections(origin: OriginFor<T>, admin: Option<T::AccountId>) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
            // Check that the extrinsic was signed by root.
            ensure_root(origin)?;           

            let account_id = Self::account_id();
            let admin = admin.unwrap_or(account_id.clone());

            //== Experience credentials ==//
            // Create collection
            T::Nfts::create_collection_with_id(
                T::ExperienceNFTCollectionId::get(), 
                &account_id, 
                &admin,
                &CollectionConfig {
                    settings: CollectionSettings::from_disabled(
                        CollectionSetting::TransferableItems | CollectionSetting::UnlockedMetadata
                    ),
                    max_supply: None,
                    mint_settings: MintSettings::default(),
                })?;

            // Set collection metadata.
            T::Nfts::set_collection_metadata(None, &T::ExperienceNFTCollectionId::get(), &[0,1])?;
            
            Ok(())
        }
```

Comment: It results in the following error:


error[E0277]: the trait bound `frame_support::dispatch::Pays: WeighData<()>` is not satisfied
   --> pallets/credentials/src/lib.rs:242:12
    |
242 |     #[pallet::call]
    |               ^^^^ the trait `WeighData<()>` is not implemented for `frame_support::dispatch::Pays`

FYI: First it gave a similar error about the admin argument, so I removed that completely, since it better to have that in Config anyway.